# Visual Basic string syntax error while trying to automate WinSCP

Tags: vba, excel, winscp

I wish to use thing string useing `Shell()` function to automate an upload of an excel file to an ftp server whenever a save occurs:

`strShell = "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe /console /command " & Chr(34) & "option batch on" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & "open user:pass@localhost" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) "put " ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "/home/User/Directory" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) "exit" & Chr(34)`

For some reason I get syntax error for this string. My knowledge in VBA isn't wide but I going over MSDNfor the last couple of hours didn't seem to help at all.

Comment: Aren't you missing a space before `/home/User/Directory`?

Comment: @jbarker2160, I am, thanks. But sadly this typo doesn't solve the syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you need more quotes for file paths containing spaces. Something like 
`strShell = "'C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe' /console /command " & Chr(34) &`....

you also forgot some "`&`" like on the 3dr line:
`Chr(34) & "put " & ThisWorkbook.Path &`
Again on that line, you *might* need to surround filenames with quotes !

Your best help would be to include a `Debug.Print strShell` and watch the result in the VBE Immediate Window (^G)

Comment: woha, I forgot more than one `&`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for WinSCP, you need to add the double quotes around your commands.  For Example:
`WinSCP.exe /command "option batch abort"`

So in VBA that would be: `"WinSCP.exe /command ""option batch abort"""`

Comment: AFAIK `Chr(34)` is `"`